# How to clear the message after page refresh in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, attributes, page-refresh

I have a jsp page & an underlying servlet which is used to upload a file from the jsp. Once the file is uploaded, it displays a message on the same jsp.
But after page refresh also, the message still displays. I tried `session.removeAttribute("Message");`
But it didnt work. 
Can anyone help please

Servlet Code

```
message = "File Uploaded Successfully";
request.setAttribute("Message", message); // forwards to the message
page.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/tabs.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Jsp Code

```
<% if (request.getAttribute("Message") != null) { %>
<div class="uploadMsg">
    <p>
        <b><%=request.getAttribute("Message")%></b>
    </p>
</div>
<% } 
session.setAttribute("Message", null); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have set the attribute in request but setting null value in session.. remove the value from request... instead of session.setAttribute("Message", null); do request.setAttribute("Message", null);

Answer (score 0):

**JSP Code**

```
String message = "Failed to registration!";
request.getSession().setAttribute("message_error", message);
response.sendRedirect("reg.jsp");
```

**Get Session Message and Clear Message After Page Refresh**

```
<c:if test="${not empty message_error}">
   <div class="alert alert-warning">
       <strong><c:out value="${message_error}"/></strong>
   </div>
   <c:set var="message_error" value="" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```